# SQL query to delete records from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, range

I am trying to write 2 queries to delete records where dates are greater than a certain date:

The first one:

```
delete from RPT_HistSnapEng_temp 
where ForecastDate> DATEADD(WEEK,7,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

This query deletes records when forecastdate is greater than 7 weeks from today

The second one is:

```
delete from RPT_HistSnapEng_temp 
where ForecastDate< DATEADD(WEEK,-6,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

This query deletes records when forecastdate is less than 6 weeks from today.

So basically, this should filter out records from Dec 2015 - Nov 2016 and only show records from previous 6 weeks and next 7 weeks from today.

Even though the query runs, its not deleting records. I cannot hardcode dates because I will be using this query on a rolling basis inside a SSIS package.

Comment: How many records are being deleted? Is it running and not finishing or running and completing without deleting anything?

Comment: Is the change being committed before you query?

Comment: so the query runs pretty quickly (within 5-15 sec) and says '0 rows affected'. There are about 4-5m records in the table. but when i do a select distinct on the forecastdate, I can see dates from entire year.

Comment: Does it return rows if you run the same query as a select?

Comment: returned 0 rows. select COUNT (*) from RPT_HistSnapEng_temp where ForecastDate< DATEADD(WEEK,-6,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

Answer (score 0):

Try "ww" or "wk" instead of "week" in the dateadd function. Try a SELECT statement to get the records you want to delete:

```
SELECT ID, ForecastDate
FROM RPT_HistSnapEng_temp 
WHERE CAST(ForecastDate AS DATE) > DATEADD(ww,7,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    OR CAST(ForecastDate AS DATE) < DATEADD(WEEK,-6,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
ORDER BY ForecastDate
```

To Delete just remove the SELECT and the ORDER BY:

```
DELETE 
FROM RPT_HistSnapEng_temp 
WHERE CAST(ForecastDate AS DATE) > DATEADD(ww,7,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
OR CAST(ForecastDate AS DATE) < DATEADD(WEEK,-6,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: how would i use the above query to delete selected records?

Comment: still says 0 rows affected I can see dates from december 2016. (I should be able to see dates only in future 7 weeks according tot his code). Should I try using alter table code instead?

Comment: Scratch that, it works perfectly, thanks a lot. I had to break the two where clauses into 2 different queries

Comment: The `and` should be `or` here.

Comment: Ack, yes, thanks @Tim! OR not AND and the one query will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your current `where` clauses are trying to grab records that are both less than a date in the past AND greater than a date in the future. I think you (and the other answer) should be using `or`.

But, since this looks like a temp table that you are loading to then report with, I would adjust your insert to simply grab the records you are looking for, rather than loading more than you need and then deleting.

```
select *
from RPT_HistSnapEng -- base table name?
where cast(ForecastDate as date) between dateadd(week, -6, cast(current_timestamp as date)) and dateadd(week, 7, cast(current_timestamp as date))
```

Just add your insert to that if it gets the records you need.

However, to directly answer your question about deletes, you can change this query to simply use NOT between:

```
delete
from RPT_HistSnapEng_temp
where cast(ForecastDate as date) not between dateadd(week, -6, cast(current_timestamp as date)) and dateadd(week, 7, cast(current_timestamp as date))
```

As you can see, I like the use of `between` (which is *inclusive* of the date arguments) for this type of range check rather than getting caught up in using `>=` and `<` or confusing the `and` and `or` which you've seemingly done. I also like the ANSI standard `current_timestamp` over the t-sql specific `getdate()` but they are equivalent.